# Retrieve Accurate External IPV4 Address PHP

Tags: php, cloudflare, php-5.2

I was watching a video on how to gather **the real external IP address of the user** in [YT:*DewClarke*]'s video. His code **worked perfectly on his website**, but **resulted with an IPV6 version on mine**: **2701:0564:d210:5be4:5b0b:8630:4c99:a3be** (randomized for privacy reasons). **How can I get the IPV4** like **216.3.128.12** (randomized for privacy reasons)?

```
<?php 
    function getUserIP(){
      $client  = @$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
      $forward = @$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
      $remote  = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
      if(filter_var($client, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)){
        $ip = $client;
      }elseif(filter_var($forward, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)){
        $ip = $forward;
      }else{
        $ip = $remote;
      }
      return $ip;
    }
    $user_ip = getUserIP();
?>
```

I "echo" the data later down the line...

```
<div id="LoggedAs"><span><?php echo $user_ip;?></span></div>
```

Some useful information is that I use 000WebHost.com, run it through CloudFlare.com, it's written in PHP, and I force SSL on that page.
DewClarke's source-code can be found here: [DewClarke's Source Code](http://dewclarke.com/myip/source_code_myip.txt)

Comment: IPV6 it is an actual IP

Comment: I'm looking for the IPV4, not IPV6, but yes, I know.

Comment: i dont think you do know, as only a small number of IPV6 address can be directly mapped to IPV4

Comment: And are you sure you are connecting to that website using IPv4? If you are on IPv6 you will get IPv6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems fine. This seems like a Cloudflare setting. Go to Cloudflare -> (your domain) -> Network. Then set IPv6 Compatibility to OFF.

It is recommended though that you keep this setting to ON because IPv6 is critical to the growth of worldwide connection of networks.

You may also be interested to use this code instead for getting the IP address and country of the connecting user as provided by Cloudflare:

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP'] : $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$_SERVER['REMOTE_COUNTRY'] = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY'] : 'Unknown';
```